# Opengl multiple glDrawArrays calls

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, 3d

I have a Problem with vertex array objects in `opengl` (`java`, `lwjgl`). 
The Program itself works, i have an object, can move around it.
The draw call is simple:

```
Gl11.glDrawArrays(drawmode, 0, 4);
```

In the shader i have one uniform for the model, (called model ^^). 
Now i tried the following: (pseudo code)

```
update the model  
draw  
update the model  
draw again
```

This doesn't work. why? I know there is instancing, but that isn't my aim here. I just want to draw 2 things with 2 draw calls. But i only see the first one.. does anyone have an idea?

** Edit **

I hate it. I hate this principe... Again and again I forget to flip the buffer before using it in opengl. Now again. That was the point... the first time i flipped it the second time not... I can't get it into my brain to flip this buffers -.-

Comment: Show the relevant code. The approach you did describe in the question so far should work in principle.

Comment: *Update the model?* That is precisely why vertex shaders were created in the first place, so that you don not update the model and then issue another draw call. Update some uniforms instead and let the vertex shader do the heavy lifting. ... In any case, a lot of what you are talking about is very vague - flipping buffers could refer to swapping your front-/back-buffers (*though now that I look at the language tag, I assume you mean flipping a Java IO buffer*), and "updating the model" could mean any number of things. You need to add some code if you want help with this.

Comment: Hm yes, you're right its very unprecise... I meant the IO buffer, yes, and with updating the model i meant glUniformMatrix4(buffer) ^^

But it works now, so thx :)